# How to align headers above Listview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a header section with 6 headers,above a listview however the header titles are not directly above my row data, some are slightly off. i've tired many solutions but it's very tricky. Some advice would be great

**Here is my list_item xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/from"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/from"
       android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#0300f1"/>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="hello"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/subject"
     />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/subject"
     android:layout_width="70dip"
     android:textColor="#000000"
      android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
     android:layout_width="60dip"
     android:textColor="#d20015"
      android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>


 <TextView android:id="@+id/mail"
     android:layout_width="60dip"
     android:textColor="#000000"
      android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/roundscore"
     android:layout_width="60dip"
     android:textColor="#000000"
      android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

**Here is my list_item xml:**

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="HEADER1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="HEADER2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="HEADER3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="HEADER4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="HEADER5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#E5E4E2"
    android:divider="#736F6E"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0"
         android:textSize="12dp"
         android:textColor="#2da6de"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        />


 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >


 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Refresh"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:textSize="11dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
      />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also provide a screenshot to show what exactly is the problem with the view?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/z1zjdpqn9/  Thanks Sharj - sorry i had to edit the data as it's a clients information

Comment: it simple user same type of layout in header and listview adapter layout(child layout). remember if you give padding,margin in listview child layout, you should give same to header.

Answer (score 0):

I give it a shot, I'm not sure to have perfectly understood your question. But you want to perfectly align your fields with your data. I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. I think it's because you have 5 fields and in your row of one item you have 6 data to put. So one side you devide your screen by 6 and on the other by five but if you put six fields like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HEADER1"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HEADER2"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HEADER3"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HEADER4"
        android:textSize="11dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HEADER5"
        android:textSize="11dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HEADER5"
        android:textSize="11dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#0300f1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="hello"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    <TextView android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#d20015"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/roundscore"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

it will work.
Edit:
So basically your textView6 is out of your LinearLayout.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the reply, apologies i pasted the wrong code version, there is a  textView6.

Comment: Can you edit and post the right code please for me to test ;)